# postbacks from inside not firing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, magnific-popup

I have a bit of ASP code that I'm trying to show/hide via Magnific Popup, by passing it a div from the page as a source.

```
<a href="#import-popup" ToolTip="Import New Proposal" class="open-popup-link">Insert New Record</a>
<div id="import-popup" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <span>Proposal to Import:</span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPropNum" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.
    });
})
```

The div displays and hides perfectly fine.  I can't seem to get the `asp:Button id="btnImport"` to actually fire it's function (which right now is a `MsgBox` to display the contents of the `asp:TextBox`) though.  In fact, I don't even see a post/get request being logged in my web console.

The button however, works fine when not located inside that div, and the `TextBox` is even accessible from code behind as well, so I know my actual click function is working.  Any ideas what might be going on?  Is Magnific somehow preventing a postback?

Comment: *If the popup moves the controls outside of the ASP.NET form then the buttons will not postback* (as they are .. outside the form; the details are slightly more involved). Tell Magnificent Popup where move the popup controls (which must be located in the one-and-only ASP.NET Form) or use a different popup with such flexibility. Use a DOM inspector after the popup runs to see where the controls have been moved.

Comment: Good call.  It is indeed bringing them outside the form.  Thanks for the fast response and accurate information.

Comment: I have the same problem... did you figure out how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up moving my popup's content to it's own page, then invoking magnific through the `iframe` type, as below:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler" style="width:100px; height:100px;">'+
                    '<div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
                    '<div class="custom-mfp-border">'+
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' +
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>'
            },
        midClick: true // Allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source in href.

    });

})
```

Parent Page:

```
<a href="/Proposals/ImportProposal.aspx" ToolTip="Insert New Record from ACT" class="open-popup-link">Insert New Record</a>
```

Then my child page is essentially just the `<div>` I posted in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of `.magnificPopup` then you can use the new `prependTo` method, and sent the .net form ID when setting it up.

```
   $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
                type: 'inline',
                preloader: false,
                focus: '#name',
                prependTo: $('#form1'),
```

Comment: Will definitely check this out when I get the chance.  Seems like exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could find for this (as I didn't see any options in the API) was to modify the core code (yuck!).

I changed the line:

```
// add everything to DOM
mfp.bgOverlay.add(mfp.wrap).prependTo( document.body );
```

to:

```
// add everything to DOM
mfp.bgOverlay.add(mfp.wrap).prependTo( $('#form1') );
```

where form1 is the ID of my form element.

Comment: What I wound up doing was building a new page to house my popup content, then invoking it via the iframe type.  I'll post my code in an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Good call! Much better than having to modify the core code.

Comment: That said, any events or postbacks in your child page are then captured by the child page, and not the parent page.

Comment: Good point. In my use, I did need the events to fire on the parent page, so this wouldn't have ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

adding prependTo: $('#form1')
worked for me! using VS 2010

Comment: providing full code samples is easier for everyone to understand, simply use the button that says copy question code to answer and then edit it.